# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException

Tags: scala, jackson

I use `JacksMapper` to parse JSON strings to `Map[String,String]`:

```
  def parseJSON(line: String): Map[String, String] = {
    JacksMapper.readValue[Map[String, String]](line)
  }
```

For some JSON strings it throws the error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
```

In particular it happens with this string:

{"id":"123","name":"visited","category":"abc","x_ids":["220"]}

I assume that the problem is with `"x_ids":["220"]`, while I expect the result as `Map[String,String]`.  So, in this case I would be interested to convert arrays to strings like `"x_ids"->"220,230"`. How can I do it flexibly so that the solution would be adaptable to other possible fields that might be arrays in some cases?

**EDIT:**
In my case I never have complex arrays that should be parsed with a static class. Only arrays of numbers or strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in two steps:

1. Parse JSON without caring of the value type
2. Map the values and transform them if needed

That could give something like:

```
def parseJSON(line: String): Map[String, String] = {
  JacksMapper.readValue[Map[String, Any]](line)
    .mapValues {
      case array: Iterable[Any] => array.mkString(", ")
      case anyValue: Any        => anyValue.toString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you claim all values are `String`s, but `x_ids` is a JSON Array, not JSON String. Two ways to go about it:

1. Declare value type as `java.lang.Object`, in which case you get `String` and `List`s
2. Enable `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS` in which case JSON Array with one (and only one!) element may be "unwrapped" to match expected type -- not 100% sure it works here, but in theory should